# Regular expression with listings to extract filename from path

Tags: listings

When using `\lstinputlisting{./../src/main.py}` I'm using relative paths to access the Python source file.

However, I would like to automatically exclude the relative path part leaving just the filename, so that the title/caption appears like this `main.py` and not like `./../src/main.py`

I would assume some regular expression could solve my problem, but how ?

Simplified LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset {
    title = \lstname % <- regular expression to extract filename
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{./../src/main.py}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is a option `inputpath=./../src/` that you can feed into `\lstset`. With that, TeX should be able to find the path-less input file in that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the path with the `inputpath` option to `\lstset` and provide the file name with an intermediary macro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset {
  inputpath=./../src,
  title = \myname
}

\begin{document}
\def\myname{main.py}
\lstinputlisting{\myname}

\def\myname{test.py}
\lstinputlisting{\myname}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: a more generic and easier to handle approach would be to strip away the path part as long as your source files are always located in a folder named `src`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\def\extractPath#1src/#2\relax{#2}
\lstset{title = \expandafter\extractPath\lstname\relax}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{./../src/main.py}
\lstinputlisting{./../src/test.py}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! It solved it nicely

Answer (score 5):

`expl3` got you covered. There is a function built in `\file_parse_full_name:nNNN`, which we can use here. I created a macro from it which you can use to typeset different parts of the file name. If the optional argument includes a `d` the directory will be printed, if it contains an `f` the file name will be printed, if it contains an `e` the extension will be printed, order doesn't matter. By default it uses `fe` so prints the file name and the extension, but not the directory (as you wanted it to be).

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_Skjerning_dir_tl
\tl_new:N \l_Skjerning_file_tl
\tl_new:N \l_Skjerning_ext_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \GetFileName { O{fe} m }
  {
    \file_parse_full_name:eNNN { #2 }
      \l_Skjerning_dir_tl 
      \l_Skjerning_file_tl 
      \l_Skjerning_ext_tl 
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #1 } { d } { \l_Skjerning_dir_tl / }
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #1 } { f } \l_Skjerning_file_tl
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #1 } { e } \l_Skjerning_ext_tl
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \file_parse_full_name:nNNN { eNNN }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstset {
  title = {\GetFileName{\lstname}}
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{./../src/main.py}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, I think I will go with @Lupino answer as it is more simply and works for this particular case. But I'll save your answer for a larger project that I have in mind.